# Uploading content to Content Version with different file owners

Tags: data-loader, content

While I'm uploading files to `ContentVersion` object, I'm receiving this error.

**"You must specify a FirstPublishLocation where you have publish permission."**

In the FirstPublishLocation , I have mentioned the owner id of the file owner.

I'm uploading files using a system admin account.

Comment: this means you are trying to upload files into the personal library of that user. see https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_settings_perms.htm&language=en_US . Users with Modify All can upload new versions but not to private libraries. How has the fiel owner defined their library's access?

Comment: There is a public library, I have migrated the files into the public library with the data migration user (using dataloader) being the owner of all the files and with SharingType set to "AllUsers". All user can access the files but is there a way that i can reserve the ownership of the files as it came from Attachments?